# Connect via telnet and doing certain operations

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, telnet

I'm trying to code a script where I can connect via telnet to another server and execute certain operations, but I'm having problems with the result of this process.

The objective is to connect to a server, execute one command, and save the result into a .txt file. It is desirable that the parameters or input are in an input file .txt, which is read by the script and executed. (I have not done that part yet.)

Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
sleep 5
echo "user"
sleep 3
echo "password"
sleep 3
echo "clear"
echo "COMMANDS" >> /ROUTE/output_file.txt
echo exit
} | telnet 172.22.89.133
```

In this case I'm getting the output file filled with the command, but obviously I need the result of that command. I know it is a little silly, but I've been trying in many ways and I am still getting the same result.

How can I get this done?

Comment: You should use `Expect` to control an interactive program like `telnet`.

Comment: maybe use nc instead of telnet

Answer (score 1):

Move the `>> /ROUTE/output_file.txt` from where it is now to the telnet line, so that line becomes `} | telnet 172.22.89.133 >> /ROUTE/output_file.txt`